# How to get TExcelWorksheet (the 64-bit version) in XE2?

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, delphi-xe2

Delphi-XE2 does not seem to have a TExcelWorksheet component.
How do I get the 64-bit version of this component installed?

[image]

A download link somewhere would be way cool, but perhaps a import for Excel 2010 64 bit will also work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install the `dclOffice2010160.bpl` design time package.

[image]

Comment: Does that apply to 64-bit targets? My understanding of the Office wrappers were that they were based on the 32-bit  version of the type libraries. (I don't have a 64-bit version of Office; I'm still using Office 2007 32-bit on my Win7 64-bit system.)

Comment: @Ken My understanding is that there is no difference between the 32 and 64 bit COM servers. Other than pointers being different widths, but the compiler simply takes care of that. We have just upgraded our Add-in Express and although I haven't tested our add-in on 64 bit Excel yet the Add-in Express stuff uses the same wrappers for both 32 and 64 bit. In fact this is really the same for all components, not just COM wrappers, because the IDE is 32 bit only.

Comment: Thanks. My question was more about the GUIDs used. I would have thought they'd be different for the 32 and 64 bit ActiveX components in the .tlb files. (Don't know much about using 64-bit ActiveX under Win64; as I said, I still have Office 32-bit.) Of course, if the answer is just to install the Office automation wrappers, it doesn't have to be the Office 2010 version; Delphi XE2 still ships with the XP and 2K wrappers as well.)

Comment: @Ken That's actually a different question that Johan asked today. It would be a total nightmare to have different GUIDs, ProgIDs etc. for 32 and 64 bit versions of the same servers so the solution is to use different registry views (32/64 bit) and let the registry redirector do that grunt work.

Comment: Yep. Just saw your answer to that at the same time your last reply showed up. :) Thanks, David. Learned something new today.

Comment: @Ken It's a really excellent solution to the problem. Just imagine if you had to do it all yourself with conditional code! What a nightmare that would be.

Comment: That really is a slick solution. Who would have thought MS would do something that smart (especially considering some of the other 32/64 decisions they made)? :)

Comment: @Ken I presume you mean the naming of `system32` and `syswow64`. I can understand their decision there and after all, it's not as if anyone other than devs should really be tinkering in there. But look at the seamless ability of the WOW64 emulator to run 32 bit code. I saw kudos to AMD and MS for this. I think all parties did a fantastic job. And as someone who waited a very long time for a 64 bit Delphi compiler, I'm glad WOW64 works so well.