# Pulling mail from OutLook to files

Tags: delphi, outlook, export, message

From my Delphi program I would like to be able to retrieve all mails from a certain folder in my OutLook and save them as files.
I will need to retrieve the sender, subject, date and message iD in order to save info in a table (if possible more parts)
I expect to save each mail in a file so I can access them later.

Comment: Is it your local Outlook you want to retrieve mail from or is it your mailbox (POP3, IMAP or Exchange server)?

Answer (score 5):

This is entirely possible. What you need is Outlook automation. Either the plain vanilla kind, or the one using the COM Server wrappers that come with Delphi. If you are on one of the newer versions of Delphi, you may have to install the corresponding package to find them on your palette. See [How to get TExcelWorksheet (the 64-bit version) in XE2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740019/how-to-get-texcelworksheet-the-64-bit-version-in-xe2/9740316#9740316) for more information.

For more information on how you can automate Outlook, go directly to the source: the MSDN for documentation on the Outlook COM object model and API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268893(v=vs.80).aspx

Another source is Deborah Pate's site on COM programming. It may not have been updated in a long while, but the information there is still good and relevant: http://www.djpate.freeserve.co.uk/Automation.htm

### Example code

Unit contains two classes to read mails in a specific folder. It uses the Outlook COM server wrapper form Delphi (a very old version), but you don't need to have them on the palette as they are instantiated in code. You do need to have the COM wrapper units on your search path of course.

Instantiate the TSiteMailList class like this:

```
FMailList := TSiteMailList.Create('MAPI', 'Folder1', 'Folder2');
```

MAPI is the Outlook MAPI NameSpace. Folder1 and Folder2 are names of outlook mail folders. 'Inbox' can be used here for the default mail inbox.

The TSiteMailList class declaration:

```
  TSiteMailList = class(TObject)
  private
    FShowUnreadOnly: boolean;
    FMails: TObjectList;

    FOutlook: TOutlookApplication;
    FNameSpace: NameSpace;
    FNewMailsFolder: MAPIFolder;
    FProcessedMailsFolder: MAPIFolder;
    function FindFolder(FolderPath: string): MAPIFolder;
    procedure LoadMails;
    function GetSiteMail(idx: integer): TSiteMail;
    function GetShowUnreadOnly: boolean;
    procedure SetShowUnreadOnly(const Value: boolean);
  protected
    function GetCount: integer;
  public
    constructor Create(MAPINameSpace: string; NewMailsFolder, ProcessedMailsFolder:
        string);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure MarkAsProcessed(SiteMail: TSiteMail);
    procedure Reload;
    property ShowUnreadOnly: boolean read GetShowUnreadOnly write SetShowUnreadOnly;
    property Count: integer read GetCount;
    property SiteMail[idx: integer]: TSiteMail read GetSiteMail;
  end;
```

Its constructor and destructor:

```
constructor TSiteMailList.Create(MAPINameSpace: string; NewMailsFolder,
    ProcessedMailsFolder: string);
begin
  FOutlook := TOutlookApplication.Create( nil );
  FOutlook.ConnectKind := ckNewInstance;
  FOutlook.Connect;
  FNameSpace := FOutlook.GetNameSpace( MAPINameSpace );
  FNameSpace.Logon( '', '', False, False );
  FNewMailsFolder := FindFolder( NewMailsFolder );
  FProcessedMailsFolder := FindFolder( ProcessedMailsFolder );

  FShowUnreadOnly := false;
  FMails := TObjectList.Create( true );
  LoadMails;
end;

destructor TSiteMailList.Destroy;
begin
  FMails.Free;
  if FNameSpace <> nil then begin
    FNameSpace.Logoff;
  end;
  FOutlook.Disconnect;
  FOutlook.Free;

  inherited;
end;
```

Outlook folder can be nested. The folder names passes into the constructor can use '\' to separate folder names. The code below parses the path and locates the corresponding Outlook folder:

```
procedure ExtractFolderFromPath(var path, folder: string);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  folder := '';
  if path[1] = '\' then begin
    path := Copy( path, 2, Length( path ) - 1 );
  end;
  i := Pos( '\', path );
  if i > 0 then begin
    folder := Copy( path, 1, i - 1 );
    path := Copy( path, i + 1, Length( path ) - i );
  end else begin
    folder := path;
    path := '';
  end;
end;

function TSiteMailList.FindFolder(FolderPath: string): MAPIFolder;
var
  path: string;
  foldername: string;
  xFolder: MAPIFolder;
begin
  path := FolderPath;
  ExtractFolderFromPath( path, foldername );
  if foldername <> '' then begin
    xFolder := FNameSpace.Folders.Item( foldername );
  end;
  while path <> '' do begin
    ExtractFolderFromPath( path, foldername );
    xFolder := xFolder.Folders.Item( foldername );
  end;
  Result := xFolder;
end;
```

The getters and setters are pretty straight forward, so I left them out. The LoadMails method is the one you would need to access each mail item in a folder:

```
procedure TSiteMailList.LoadMails;
var
  i: integer;
  GeneralItem: IDispatch;
  MI: MailItem;
begin
  FMails.Clear;
  for i := 1 to FNewMailsFolder.Items.Count do begin
    GeneralItem := FNewMailsFolder.Items.Item( i );
    if Sysutils.Supports(GeneralItem, MailItem, MI) then begin
      if not FShowUnreadOnly
      or ( FShowUnreadOnly and ( MI.Unread = true ) )
      then begin
        FMails.Add( TSiteMail.Create( i, MI ) );
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The TSiteMailList uses the TSiteMail class to keep track of information about Outlook mail items in the folder specified by the first folder parameter of its constructor. The TSiteMail class declaration:

```
  TSiteMail = class(TObject)
  private
    FOutlookIdx: integer;
    FMailItem: MailItem;
    function GetIsRead: boolean;
    procedure SetIsRead(const Value: boolean);
  protected
    function GetBody: string;
    function GetFileCount: integer;
    function GetFileName(idx: integer): string;
    function GetReceived: TDateTime;
    function GetSender: string;
    function GetSubject: string;
  public
    constructor Create(idx: integer; MI: MailItem);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function IndexOfFileName(Name: string): integer;
    procedure MoveToFolder(Folder: MAPIFolder);
    procedure SaveFile(idx: integer; FileName: string);

    property Body: string read GetBody;
    property FileCount: integer read GetFileCount;
    property FileName[idx: integer]: string read GetFileName;
    property IsRead: boolean read GetIsRead write SetIsRead;
    property Received: TDateTime read GetReceived;
    property Sender: string read GetSender;
    property Subject: string read GetSubject;
  end;
```

And its implementation:

```
constructor TSiteMail.Create(idx: integer; MI: MailItem);
begin
  FOutlookIdx := idx;
  FMailItem := MI;
end;

destructor TSiteMail.Destroy;
begin
  FMailItem := nil; // Release interface
  inherited;
end;

function TSiteMail.GetBody: string;
begin
  Result := FMailItem.Body;
end;

function TSiteMail.GetFileCount: integer;
begin
  Result := FMailItem.Attachments.Count;
end;

function TSiteMail.GetFileName(idx: integer): string;
begin
  Result := FMailItem.Attachments.Item( idx + 1 ).FileName;
end;

function TSiteMail.GetIsRead: boolean;
begin
  Result := not FMailItem.UnRead;
end;

function TSiteMail.GetReceived: TDateTime;
begin
  Result := FMailItem.ReceivedTime;
end;

function TSiteMail.GetSender: string;
begin
  Result := FMailItem.SenderName;
end;

function TSiteMail.GetSubject: string;
begin
  Result := FMailItem.Subject;
end;

function TSiteMail.IndexOfFileName(Name: string): integer;
var
  idx: integer;
begin
  Result := -1;
  for idx := 1 to FMailItem.Attachments.Count do begin
    if CompareText( Name, FMailItem.Attachments.Item( idx ).FileName ) = 0 then begin
      Result := idx - 1;
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TSiteMail.MoveToFolder(Folder: MAPIFolder);
begin
  FMailItem.Move( Folder );
end;

procedure TSiteMail.SaveFile(idx: integer; FileName: string);
begin
  FMailItem.Attachments.Item( idx + 1 ).SaveAsFile( FileName );
end;

procedure TSiteMail.SetIsRead(const Value: boolean);
begin
  FMailItem.UnRead := not Value;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you all for the info - I will have to test it and see what I can get out of it

Comment: Is it possible that yo have the units in files and perhaps a small test of what they can do?
I am a bit pressed for time at the moment and before I use many hours on your input it would be nice to se what it can do.

Comment: @OZ8HP: Sorry, no, while the code is in a separate unit, it is part of largish project and would take me far too much time to create a working example app from it.

Comment: OK - but if you stumble over the unit one day I would love to get a copy
My mail is  oz8hp  @  hotmail  .  com